# add straight lines to parity plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following figure in LaTeX:

[image]

And I want to add the error lines (+5%, 0% and -5%) present in the following figure:

[image]

Can anyone help me please?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,BCOR=15mm,bibliography=totoc,DIV=9,final,headings=optiontohead,
listof=chaptergapsmall,listof=totoc,numbers=noenddot,openright,parskip=half,titlepage,twoside,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman,english,]{babel} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}       
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.23]
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    a={mark=square*,blue},%
    b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    c={mark=o,draw=black}},
    %enlargelimits=0.05,
    xmax=0.8,
    ]
    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
%   \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        %coordinates {
        table[meta=label] {
x                   y                   label
0.002112423     0.000315235     a
0.008239025     0.018046369     a
0.062159889     0.043377048     a
0.208436752     0.228901981     a   
0.001133101     0.000154947     a
0.040467529     0.027339084     a
0.089692556     0.064237734     a
0.28676767      0.31508994      a
0.002850088     0.000642276     a
0.021743629     0.024458691     a
0.079502818     0.057741852     a
0.254297655     0.287565373     a
0.000380747     0.000164715     a           
0.032442275     0.030100629     a
0.094151846     0.069629312     a
0.294738866     0.324776721     a
0.00304861      0.000381536     a
0.019427897     0.020999092     a
0.062143477     0.048076131     a   
0.194015639     0.216910177     a
0.003349286     0.000441544     a
0.020499155     0.022771878     a
0.067614017     0.051923091     a
0.207662339     0.231218823     a
0.003266332     0.00034481      a
0.035174329     0.026984827     a
0.081134664     0.060966461     a
0.244687574     0.263579365     a   
0.003885047     0.000548398     a
0.026061176     0.02816921      a
0.083494892     0.064074034     a
0.254794902     0.283107698     a
0.00319197      0.00052752      a
0.026602327     0.02220633      a
0.069674766     0.050513108     a
0.207840599     0.223222373     a
0.012393            0.017580388     b
0.033038            0.080750236     b
0.015539            0.000107785     b
0.012579            0.054686291     b
0.102741            0.099809908     b
0.66043         0.643811883     b
0.16328         0.103253509     b
0.004               0.002069047     b
0.0084          0.028962671     b
0.0043          0.000156147     b
0.003               0.020684598     b
0.0978          0.106905039     b
0.7013          0.714270297     b
0.1812          0.126952202     b
0.0091          0.015147325     b
0.0297          0.077014777     b
0.0171          0.000147157     b
0.0091          0.056200871     b
0.0982          0.099332905     b
0.6678          0.633262363     b
0.169               0.118894602     b
0.0045          0.000940978     b
0.01                0.01989367      b
0.0073          0.000192736     b
0.0027          0.014700027     b
0.1102          0.10791124      b
0.688               0.715603802     b
0.1773          0.140757548     b
0.0092          0.017839841     b
0.0299          0.075399115     b
0.015               0.000180757     b
0.0115          0.055440993     b
0.0996          0.093268175     b
0.6664          0.631287207     b   
0.1684          0.126583912     b
0.0138          0.022462525     b
0.036               0.082664867     b
0.0165          0.000171887     b
0.0144          0.05990831      b
0.0968          0.09266199      b
0.6564          0.618675107     b
0.1661          0.123455313     b
0.0136          0.013257438     b
0.0316          0.063599076     b
0.0145          0.000197003     b
0.0125          0.046716642     b   
0.1001          0.09503671      b   
0.6503          0.647679584     b
0.1774          0.133513547     b
0.0127          0.016519353     b
0.0302          0.072784494     b   
0.0142          0.000194035     b
0.0118          0.054135158     b
0.1024          0.093932615     b
0.6565          0.63106802      b
0.1722          0.131366325     b
0.013               0.016654323     b   
0.0336          0.073114749     b
0.0154          0.000194379     b
0.0136          0.055035497     b
0.0924          0.09886295      b
0.6443          0.619629408     b
0.1877          0.136508694     b
0.024               0.006083101     c
0.223               0.18314527      c
0.59                0.606819403     c
0.163               0.146526013     c
0.024               0.007344733     c
0.223               0.196607483     c
0.59                0.584792817     c
0.163               0.144862825     c
0.024               0.007817225     c
0.223               0.20413853      c
0.59                0.582885899     c
0.163               0.142905491     c
0.024               0.008610924     c   
0.223               0.208141813     c
0.59                0.569981623     c
0.163               0.143373566     c       
0.024               0.00897616      c
0.223               0.207996045     c
0.59                0.565291614     c
0.163               0.144368047     c   
0.024               0.008844303     c
0.223               0.205857591     c
0.59                0.570027159     c
0.163               0.144996868     c
0.024               0.009433456     c
0.223               0.210055677     c
0.59                0.562714293     c
0.163               0.144459927     c   
0.024               0.009496595     c
0.223               0.212698833     c
0.59                0.560711551     c
0.163               0.14351753      c
0.024               0.010050341     c
0.223               0.219992169     c
0.59                0.567247848     c
0.163               0.141241314     c
                };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Nice caption}
\label{fig:selectivity2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `regression plot`s may help to achieve what you want. In order not to have a too bulky code, I also load the data in a table macro.

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,BCOR=15mm,bibliography=totoc,DIV=9,final,headings=optiontohead,
listof=chaptergapsmall,listof=totoc,numbers=noenddot,openright,parskip=half,titlepage,twoside,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman,english,]{babel} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}       
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\pgfplotstableread{
x                   y                   label
0.002112423     0.000315235     a
0.008239025     0.018046369     a
0.062159889     0.043377048     a
0.208436752     0.228901981     a   
0.001133101     0.000154947     a
0.040467529     0.027339084     a
0.089692556     0.064237734     a
0.28676767      0.31508994      a
0.002850088     0.000642276     a
0.021743629     0.024458691     a
0.079502818     0.057741852     a
0.254297655     0.287565373     a
0.000380747     0.000164715     a           
0.032442275     0.030100629     a
0.094151846     0.069629312     a
0.294738866     0.324776721     a
0.00304861      0.000381536     a
0.019427897     0.020999092     a
0.062143477     0.048076131     a   
0.194015639     0.216910177     a
0.003349286     0.000441544     a
0.020499155     0.022771878     a
0.067614017     0.051923091     a
0.207662339     0.231218823     a
0.003266332     0.00034481      a
0.035174329     0.026984827     a
0.081134664     0.060966461     a
0.244687574     0.263579365     a   
0.003885047     0.000548398     a
0.026061176     0.02816921      a
0.083494892     0.064074034     a
0.254794902     0.283107698     a
0.00319197      0.00052752      a
0.026602327     0.02220633      a
0.069674766     0.050513108     a
0.207840599     0.223222373     a
0.012393            0.017580388     b
0.033038            0.080750236     b
0.015539            0.000107785     b
0.012579            0.054686291     b
0.102741            0.099809908     b
0.66043         0.643811883     b
0.16328         0.103253509     b
0.004               0.002069047     b
0.0084          0.028962671     b
0.0043          0.000156147     b
0.003               0.020684598     b
0.0978          0.106905039     b
0.7013          0.714270297     b
0.1812          0.126952202     b
0.0091          0.015147325     b
0.0297          0.077014777     b
0.0171          0.000147157     b
0.0091          0.056200871     b
0.0982          0.099332905     b
0.6678          0.633262363     b
0.169               0.118894602     b
0.0045          0.000940978     b
0.01                0.01989367      b
0.0073          0.000192736     b
0.0027          0.014700027     b
0.1102          0.10791124      b
0.688               0.715603802     b
0.1773          0.140757548     b
0.0092          0.017839841     b
0.0299          0.075399115     b
0.015               0.000180757     b
0.0115          0.055440993     b
0.0996          0.093268175     b
0.6664          0.631287207     b   
0.1684          0.126583912     b
0.0138          0.022462525     b
0.036               0.082664867     b
0.0165          0.000171887     b
0.0144          0.05990831      b
0.0968          0.09266199      b
0.6564          0.618675107     b
0.1661          0.123455313     b
0.0136          0.013257438     b
0.0316          0.063599076     b
0.0145          0.000197003     b
0.0125          0.046716642     b   
0.1001          0.09503671      b   
0.6503          0.647679584     b
0.1774          0.133513547     b
0.0127          0.016519353     b
0.0302          0.072784494     b   
0.0142          0.000194035     b
0.0118          0.054135158     b
0.1024          0.093932615     b
0.6565          0.63106802      b
0.1722          0.131366325     b
0.013               0.016654323     b   
0.0336          0.073114749     b
0.0154          0.000194379     b
0.0136          0.055035497     b
0.0924          0.09886295      b
0.6443          0.619629408     b
0.1877          0.136508694     b
0.024               0.006083101     c
0.223               0.18314527      c
0.59                0.606819403     c
0.163               0.146526013     c
0.024               0.007344733     c
0.223               0.196607483     c
0.59                0.584792817     c
0.163               0.144862825     c
0.024               0.007817225     c
0.223               0.20413853      c
0.59                0.582885899     c
0.163               0.142905491     c
0.024               0.008610924     c   
0.223               0.208141813     c
0.59                0.569981623     c
0.163               0.143373566     c       
0.024               0.00897616      c
0.223               0.207996045     c
0.59                0.565291614     c
0.163               0.144368047     c   
0.024               0.008844303     c
0.223               0.205857591     c
0.59                0.570027159     c
0.163               0.144996868     c
0.024               0.009433456     c
0.223               0.210055677     c
0.59                0.562714293     c
0.163               0.144459927     c   
0.024               0.009496595     c
0.223               0.212698833     c
0.59                0.560711551     c
0.163               0.14351753      c
0.024               0.010050341     c
0.223               0.219992169     c
0.59                0.567247848     c
0.163               0.141241314     c
}{\loadedtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.23]
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
    a={mark=square*,blue},%
    b={mark=triangle*,red},%
    c={mark=o,draw=black}},
    %enlargelimits=0.05,
    xmax=0.8,
    ]
    % \addplot[] is better than \addplot+[] here:
    % it avoids scalings of the cycle list
%   \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        %coordinates {
        table[meta=label] {\loadedtable};
    \addplot[color=blue]  table [y={create col/linear regression={y=y}}] {\loadedtable}
    coordinate[pos=0] (start) coordinate[pos=1] (end);
    \xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona} 
    \xdef\offset{\pgfplotstableregressionb} 
    \addplot[dashed,domain=0:0.75] {\slope*x+\offset+0.05}
    node[pos=0.75,above left]{$+5\%$};
    \addplot[dashed,domain=0:0.75] {\slope*x+\offset-0.05}
    node[pos=0.75,below right]{$-5\%$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Nice caption}
\label{fig:selectivity2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is not a regression plot. Anyway, in the example you presented, there is a way to add the legend to the dotted lines in the graphic area, like in the sample image I uploaded?

Comment: In the example, is a regression plot. However, for the purpose I want, is to show the deviation between experimental data vs model obtained values (not to see the relation between two variables).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to draw a parity plot. For that no regression is needed; you just need to plot straight lines which is a very easy task.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % define some parameters so one does not have to repeat it over and over again
    /pgf/declare function={
        Min = 0;
        Max = 0.8;
        Error = 0.05;
        NodePos = 0.8;
    },
]
    \begin{axis}[
        scatter/classes={
            a={mark=square*,blue},
            b={mark=triangle*,red},
            c={mark=o,draw=black}%
        },
        % use the above declared parameters here
        xmin=Min,   xmax=Max,
        ymin=Min,   ymax=Max,
        domain=Min:Max,
        % because we only want to draw straight lines, we only need 2 samples
        samples=2,
        % if the difference between the values on the x- and y-axis should have the same length ...
        axis equal image,
    ]
        % draw the diagonal
        \addplot [black]  {x};
        % draw the error lines ...
        \addplot [dashed] {(1+Error)*x}
            % ... together with the corresponding nodes
            node [pos=NodePos,above left] {%
                \pgfmathparse{Error*100}%
                $+\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%$%
            }
        ;
        \addplot [dashed] {(1-Error)*x}
            node [pos=NodePos,below right] {%
                \pgfmathparse{Error*100}%
                $-\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%$%
            }
        ;

        % draw the data points
        \addplot [
            scatter,
            only marks,
            scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        ] table [meta=label] {
            x               y               label
            0.002112423     0.000315235     a
            0.008239025     0.018046369     a
            0.062159889     0.043377048     a
            0.208436752     0.228901981     a
            0.001133101     0.000154947     a
            0.040467529     0.027339084     a
            0.089692556     0.064237734     a
            0.28676767      0.31508994      a
            0.002850088     0.000642276     a
            0.021743629     0.024458691     a
            0.079502818     0.057741852     a
            0.254297655     0.287565373     a
            0.000380747     0.000164715     a
            0.032442275     0.030100629     a
            0.094151846     0.069629312     a
            0.294738866     0.324776721     a
            0.00304861      0.000381536     a
            0.019427897     0.020999092     a
            0.062143477     0.048076131     a
            0.194015639     0.216910177     a
            0.003349286     0.000441544     a
            0.020499155     0.022771878     a
            0.067614017     0.051923091     a
            0.207662339     0.231218823     a
            0.003266332     0.00034481      a
            0.035174329     0.026984827     a
            0.081134664     0.060966461     a
            0.244687574     0.263579365     a
            0.003885047     0.000548398     a
            0.026061176     0.02816921      a
            0.083494892     0.064074034     a
            0.254794902     0.283107698     a
            0.00319197      0.00052752      a
            0.026602327     0.02220633      a
            0.069674766     0.050513108     a
            0.207840599     0.223222373     a
            0.012393        0.017580388     b
            0.033038        0.080750236     b
            0.015539        0.000107785     b
            0.012579        0.054686291     b
            0.102741        0.099809908     b
            0.66043         0.643811883     b
            0.16328         0.103253509     b
            0.004           0.002069047     b
            0.0084          0.028962671     b
            0.0043          0.000156147     b
            0.003           0.020684598     b
            0.0978          0.106905039     b
            0.7013          0.714270297     b
            0.1812          0.126952202     b
            0.0091          0.015147325     b
            0.0297          0.077014777     b
            0.0171          0.000147157     b
            0.0091          0.056200871     b
            0.0982          0.099332905     b
            0.6678          0.633262363     b
            0.169           0.118894602     b
            0.0045          0.000940978     b
            0.01            0.01989367      b
            0.0073          0.000192736     b
            0.0027          0.014700027     b
            0.1102          0.10791124      b
            0.688           0.715603802     b
            0.1773          0.140757548     b
            0.0092          0.017839841     b
            0.0299          0.075399115     b
            0.015           0.000180757     b
            0.0115          0.055440993     b
            0.0996          0.093268175     b
            0.6664          0.631287207     b
            0.1684          0.126583912     b
            0.0138          0.022462525     b
            0.036           0.082664867     b
            0.0165          0.000171887     b
            0.0144          0.05990831      b
            0.0968          0.09266199      b
            0.6564          0.618675107     b
            0.1661          0.123455313     b
            0.0136          0.013257438     b
            0.0316          0.063599076     b
            0.0145          0.000197003     b
            0.0125          0.046716642     b
            0.1001          0.09503671      b
            0.6503          0.647679584     b
            0.1774          0.133513547     b
            0.0127          0.016519353     b
            0.0302          0.072784494     b
            0.0142          0.000194035     b
            0.0118          0.054135158     b
            0.1024          0.093932615     b
            0.6565          0.63106802      b
            0.1722          0.131366325     b
            0.013           0.016654323     b
            0.0336          0.073114749     b
            0.0154          0.000194379     b
            0.0136          0.055035497     b
            0.0924          0.09886295      b
            0.6443          0.619629408     b
            0.1877          0.136508694     b
            0.024           0.006083101     c
            0.223           0.18314527      c
            0.59            0.606819403     c
            0.163           0.146526013     c
            0.024           0.007344733     c
            0.223           0.196607483     c
            0.59            0.584792817     c
            0.163           0.144862825     c
            0.024           0.007817225     c
            0.223           0.20413853      c
            0.59            0.582885899     c
            0.163           0.142905491     c
            0.024           0.008610924     c
            0.223           0.208141813     c
            0.59            0.569981623     c
            0.163           0.143373566     c
            0.024           0.00897616      c
            0.223           0.207996045     c
            0.59            0.565291614     c
            0.163           0.144368047     c
            0.024           0.008844303     c
            0.223           0.205857591     c
            0.59            0.570027159     c
            0.163           0.144996868     c
            0.024           0.009433456     c
            0.223           0.210055677     c
            0.59            0.562714293     c
            0.163           0.144459927     c
            0.024           0.009496595     c
            0.223           0.212698833     c
            0.59            0.560711551     c
            0.163           0.14351753      c
            0.024           0.010050341     c
            0.223           0.219992169     c
            0.59            0.567247848     c
            0.163           0.141241314     c
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]